# Can some one explain how transliteration works?

Tags: python, django, translate, transliteration

I am new to programming, and I am trying to understand transliteration - like the Google Input Tools that will allow the user to type from one language to another language.

How does transliteration work? Specifically, if I am translating from English to Hindi or English to Russsian, do I need to incorporate a dictionary of words for English, Hindi and Russian languages?

Does any one know of any tutorials showing how to write the code for transliteration? I have tried searching, but no luck.

Also, does the code have to be in JavaScript/JQuery (client side code)? My project is Python/django. Can I write the transliteration code in python/dgango?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is linked to NLP, one of the most daunting fields in CS. The books on this subject are bigger than bibles. I fear your question is away too broad - it is like asking "how do I write an operational system?".

Comment: Actually, the question is different (see my now deleted answer). It's not about translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the better search term is **Input Method Editor** not transliteration.

There is a project on github here: https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.ime that deals with IME's and transliteration here.

I hope that this helps some one.

Comment: Indeed, you were searching something completely different from what you described in your question. It would be better then to change the title of your question, to better explain what you were searching. In this way, people searching for a *Multilanguage textarea in javascript* will find your answer. I suggest also to replace the tags, since they are all unrelated to your real question.

Answer (score 0):

Direct dictionary-to-dictionary automatic translation produces poor results due to differences in grammar and the presence of idiomatic sentences. The starting point in python, in my experience, should be **NLTK** (Natural Language ToolKit) [libraries](http://nltk.org/) and [tutorials](http://nltk.org/book/).

Then, trying to provide you a working example you may start from here:

- [Machine Translation using babelize_shell() in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267544/machine-translation-using-babelize-shell-in-nltk)
- [Translating human languages in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316386/translating-human-languages-in-python)
- [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=machine%20translation%20python)
- [Bing is your friend](http://bing.com/search?q=machine%20translation%20python)

The use of javascript/jquery depends on the UI you are planning, maybe you want to trigger an automatic translation after a few key pressed, or `onblur` or `onchange` in a `input` tag but is not relevant for the translation itself.

The process of translating is also really resource consuming, so I discourage you to do it inside a django view. My suggestion is to not reinvent the wheel, and use some already existing API like google or bing ones.

Comment: Since the question is poorly posed, but the answer should be related to that precise question (despite it is clearly too broad), I'd kindly like to know by the downvoter how I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of implementing transliteration is to use a mapping dictionary. An example of this can be seen in the [mapping.py](https://github.com/opendatakosovo/cyrillic-transliteration/blob/master/cyrtranslit/mapping.py) file for the [CyrTranslit](https://github.com/opendatakosovo/cyrillic-transliteration) Python package.

Answer (score 0):

Word translation usages a database to convert English word into Hindi Word.
Some apps are based on this concept like:

[English to Hindi Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hindi.dictionary)